# specify Open With application for stacks

Tags: dock, defaults

My application preferences were reset, and at which point the 'Open In Finder' arrow on the stacks is now opening iPhoto. Does anybody know how to change this?

Comment: What folder is "stacked"? What are the contents of that folder?

Comment: "stacks" are the folder views in the dock:

http://cl.ly/4GZT

Comment: and its just the regular Downloads folder, there is nothing in it as you can see in the screenshot above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Finder.app had become corrupted, I was able to re-install Finder.app (without needed to re-install my entire system) with Pacifist found at http://www.charlessoft.com/.